# When and how does cython do boundscheck?

Tags: cython

c doesn't do bounds check. So how does cython do the check if it compiles to c?

```
%%cython --annotate
cimport cython
@cython.boundscheck(True)
cpdef myf():
    cdef double pd[8]
    for i in range(100):
        pd[i] = 0
        print pd[i]
```

The above code compiles to the same C code no matter whether I set `True` or `False` for `boundscheck`. And if I run `myf()` there is no warnings (it happens to not crash...).

#### Update

So cython doens't do bounds check on c arrays anyway.

Comment: Note: there exist malloc tools for c/c++ (replacing the system libraries' malloc/new) that ensure that out of bound accesses will generate a segfault, such as DUMA or Electric Fence. These tools come with a performance overhead, but could be what you are looking for in your tests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://docs.cython.org/src/reference/compilation.html#compiler-directives

"Cython is free to assume that indexing operations ([]-operator) in the code will not cause any IndexErrors to be raised. Lists, tuples, and strings are affected..."

I think in your code a C double array doesn't store its length anywhere, and so it's impossible for Cython to do any useful checks (except in your very trivial example). However, a built in Python type which can raise `IndexError`s should be different (I'd assume numpy arrays, python arrays and cython memoryviews should also be affected since they all have a mechanism for Cython to tell if it's gone off the end).

Comment: I have a [Cython post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41944883/verifying-compatibility-in-compiling-extension-types-and-using-them-with-cdef) you may be able to provide insight on.